TypeScript : Keep Month and Year to date
I have one date, I would like to take month and year to this date in Typescript.
For example:
If I have lun. 1 juil. 2024, my code must be return juil 2024.
Can you help me please?

Can you add your attempted code to your question?

Although this is overkill, you might want to take a look at NgRx, if you will need more comprehensive state management capabilities.

You can use a map for the months, then use Date() and toLocaleDateString():
const months: { [key: string]: string } = {
  "juil.": "Jul", // map your month like this
};

function getDate(dt: string): string {
  const D = dt.split(" ");
  const day = D[1];
  const month = months[D[2]];
  const year = D[3];
  const date = new Date(`${month} ${day} ${year}`);
  const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
    month: "short",
    year: "numeric",
  };
  const dfr = date.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options);
  const [m, y] = dfr.split(" ");
  return `${m.replace(".", "")} ${y}`;
}

console.log(getDate("lun. 1 juil. 2024"));



Prints
juil 2024


Or you can use a pattern to match it:
function matchDate(dt: string): string {
  const match = dt.match(/(\w+)\.?\s+(\d{4})/);
  return match ? `${match[1]} ${match[2]}` : "";
}

console.log(matchDate("lun. 1 juil. 2024"));


Pritns
juil 2024


If i have in input date format Date => lun 1 juil 2024 , i would like my code to return the string => "juil 2024". Please, how can i do it ?

In the second approach,  your format input is a "string" (dt: string) not Date format. Now i have input date format like lundi 1 juillet 2024.
